# Jetpack compose - Border for Image reduces padding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
    @Composable
fun BottomStrip() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp)
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_background_grey)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cgux_ic_keyboard_16),
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(36.dp)
                .height(36.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base)))
                .padding(5.dp)
                .clickable {},
            contentDescription = "Expandable Image",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint( colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base))
        )
    }
}
```

I have a composable function as above . My idea is to align image to right of Row with some padding on all sides of Image.
I also have to create border around image , which I did using border modifier.
The problem I'm facing is when I set border to Image , the padding is lost which means I don't see padding for Image. Image touch right end of the screen.Is there a way we can have padding for border as well.?

[image]

Comment: If you need 5.dp space between image border and row 'border', you should apply padding to the row, not image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the padding before border will solve your problem. Below is the full code.

```
  @Composable
fun BottomStrip() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp)
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_background_grey)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cgux_ic_keyboard_16),
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(36.dp)
                .height(36.dp)
                .padding(5.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base)))
                .padding(5.dp)
                .clickable {},
            contentDescription = "Expandable Image",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint( colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base))
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jetpack compose the order of modifiers is important. [Official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters)

You can use this solution and add padding before setting size for your image:

```
@Composable
fun BottomStrip() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp)
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_background_grey)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cgux_ic_keyboard_16),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp) // padding between Row and Image, you can remove it because you already set size for Image and Row
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base)))
                .padding(5.dp) // padding between border and image
                .size(36.dp)
                .clickable {},
            contentDescription = "Expandable Image",
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint( colorResource(id = R.color.cgux_primary_500_base))
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
@Composable
fun BottomStrip() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(70.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Cyan),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_visa),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red))
                .clickable {},
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

[image]